# how to get ods file format data in php

Tags: php, ods

I am upload .ODS file in that file there are 6 fields & 1 row but when i am using below code email not fetch but other data display.

```js
$inputFileName = 'uploads/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);


               $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
                $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
                $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
                $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();                
                $response['Existing_Customers'] = array();

                $check_updated_data = array();

                for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
                    //  Read a r ow of data into an array
                    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
    //                echo "data";
                    $sr_no = $rowData[0][0];
                    $Cust_name = $rowData[0][1];
                    $Customer_No = $rowData[0][2];
                    $Customer_Email_id = $rowData[0][3];                
                    $Customer_Gender = $rowData[0][4];
                    $Customer_Address = $rowData[0][5]; }
```

Comment: Is the email address a mailto link?

Comment: But want email how to get email?

Comment: If the email address is nothing more than cell content, then it' no different to any other cell content like gender or address; so clearly it isn't otherwise you'd get it in the same way you get those other cell values..... I'm asking in what way is it different, and the most obvious is if it's a link?